# Передача сотрудника в заказ

Tags: json, мойсклад-api

Помимо прочих параметров, передаём в заказ сотрудника таким образом:

```
,"operator":{"meta":{"href":"https:\/\/online.moysklad.ru\/api\/remap\/1.1\/entity\/employee\/6523eab1-a9a7-11e7-7a6c-d2a9000488de","metadataHref":"https:\/\/online.moysklad.ru\/api\/remap\/1.1\/entity\/employee\/metadata","type":"employee","mediaType":"application\/json","uuidHref":"https:\/\/online.moysklad.ru\/app\/#employee\/edit?id=6523eab1-a9a7-11e7-7a6c-d2a9000488de"}},
```

Ошибок никаких не возникает, но он не попадает вот сюда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как нам это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки не возникает, так как поле "operator" игнорируется.
Вы хотите проставить "owner"-а заказа покупателя.

Попробуйте передать вместо "operator" - "owner"